# How to set database with AdomdConnection

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, ssas

When I execute this code:

```
AdomdConnection con = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=MyServer;User ID=MyDomain\\MyUserName;Password=MyPassword");
con.Open();

con.ChangeDatabase("Analysis Services Project1");
```

I get this exception:

> Either the user, MyDomain\MyUserName$, does not have access to the
>   Analysis Services Project1 database, or the database does not exist.

The database name comes from looking at the server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. If I bring up the properties on the server and go to the security section, my account is listed as a Server administrator. While in management studio, I can see data sources, cubes and execute mdx queries fine.

Why can't do I get this exception in code?

Answer (score 0):

whihc line causes the error?
I imagine you have to infor the catalog on your connection string. Try addind

```
Catalog=Analysis Services Project1
```

to your con string.

Also, Analysis Services Project1 seems to be the projects name? Are you sure this is the database name as well?

Comment: In my code the con.ChangeDatabase("..... line throws the exception. If I use the Catalog=... in the connection string I still get the error, its just delayed until I try to read something. I believe "Analysis Services Project1" is the database name because that it was is listed directly underneath the Databases in Sql Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

First 
added the reference for Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll

```
strCon = "Data Source=DBserverServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DBName;";
AdomdConnection con = new AdomdConnection("connectionstring"); // connect DB con.Open(); AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand("MDX query", con); //query    
AdomdDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Execute query
while (reader.Read())   // read
    {
        Data dt = new Data();  // custom class
        dt.Gender = reader[0].ToString();

        dt.Eid = reader[1].ToString();
        dt.salary = reader[2].ToString();
        data.Add(dt);
    }
```